# Can someone please help me with a solution to this problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am a novice in solving DSA problems. I am stuck to start an approach to this problem. Can someone please provide me help or reference to this problem?

**Question**

> N people are standing in a queue based on descending order of their age, find the last person's name with the given age K. If not found, return "Not found".

**Input Format**

- First line contains two integers N, K - Number of people, the given age.
- Second line contains N integers - The ages of people.
- Third line contains N strings - The names of people.

**Output Format**

- Print the name of the last person with the given age or "Not found" if not present.

**Sample Input**

```
6 30
80 30 30 7 3 3
Sam Will Roy Lane Pam Jim
```

**Sample Output**

```
Roy
```

**Explanation**

- The people with age 30 in order are Will, Roy. The last person from them is "Roy".

Constraints

```
1 <= N <= 10^5
1 <= K, Age[i] <= 10^5
1 <= |Person's name| <= 10
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class FindLastPersonOfAgeK{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        List<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ages.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            people.add(sc.next());
        }
        String ans = findLastPersonOfAgeK(ages, people, k);
        System.out.println(ans);
        sc.close();
    }

    static String findLastPersonOfAgeK(List<Integer> ages, List<String> people, int k){
         
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you're facing?

Comment: I am not able to think of which data structure would help me solve the problem

Comment: @shrimaan0205 Please specify your question and input format clearly

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I have edited the question, now I hope its clear.

Comment: Your lists are suitable for this task (as well as arrays, arraylists etc). You can also use list/array of pairs(age,name).

Comment: Binary search it out since it is in sorted state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `List` since you know the number of elements – it is the first number on the first line of input entered by the user. In the code in your question, it is the variable `n`. Hence you can use arrays rather than `List`s.

Assuming the input is always valid, i.e. all the integers are not negative and the ages are entered in descending order, all you need do is iterate the `ages` array in reverse order. Once you find an element of `ages` that equals `k`, you have found the last element. Get its index and return the element in `people` at that index.

As an optimization, once an element in `ages` is greater than `k`, there is no need to continue iterating through `ages`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindLastPersonOfAgeK {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int[] ages = new int[n];
        String[] people = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ages[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            people[i] = sc.next();
        }
        String ans = findLastPersonOfAgeK(ages, people, k);
        System.out.println(ans);
        sc.close();
    }

    static String findLastPersonOfAgeK(int[] ages, String[] people, int k) {
        for (int i = ages.length; --i >= 0;) {
            if (ages[i] == k) {
                return people[i];
            }
            else if (ages[i] > k) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return "Not found";
    }
}
```

Note that after calling method `nextInt` (of class `java.util.Scanner`) and before calling method `next` (also of class `java.util.Scanner`) you need to call method `nextLine`. Refer to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

When I run the above code, using the sample input from your question, I get the following:

```
6 30
80 30 30 7 3 3
Sam Will Roy Lane Pam Jim
Roy
```

The first three lines above are the inputs and the last line is the value returned by method `findLastPersonOfAgeK`.

Comment: Hey thanks for making it simple to understand, it is much more simple if we do not use list.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of pointers to help you out:

1. Array/list is a suitable data structure for this problem.
2. To improve the complexity of searching, you can use binary search to find the index of the last element with `age = K`.
3. Using the found index, you can find the name of the person.

Comment: Hey, thanks for providing an approach.

Comment: @shrimaan0205 if it solves your intended purpose, consider marking it as the accepted answer